# sf point object plot: fixed border color and different background colors

Tags: r, plot, r-sf

I'm having a hard time plotting an `sf` point object.
Basically I want to show the points with a black border and a fill color according to a variable. 
In base plot I would do this to impose border color with different background colors:

```
plot(1:3, cex = 3, pch = 21, col = 'red', bg = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow'), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

I use `pch = 21` in order to fill the points with `bg` colors while using `col = 'red'` as the point border color.

Using a `sf` object I can use `col` to impose the border color but the legend disappears (according to the documentation for `plot {sf}`, if `col` is passed to the function the legend is suppressed).

```
library(sf)
# example
df <- data.frame(est = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
             long = c(-70, -68, -69), 
             lat = c(-12.2, -12.4, -12), 
             RMSE = c(25, 8, 55)) %>% 
    st_as_sf(coords = c('long', 'lat'), crs = 4326)

# reclassifying the RMSE variable:
df$rmse_cut <- cut(df$RMSE, c(0,15,30,45,60))

# plotting the map
plot(df['rmse_cut'], main = 'RMSE', graticule = TRUE, axes = TRUE, 
bgc = 'gray92', 
pch = 21, lwd = 2, cex = 3,
col = 'black', 
bg = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow'))
```

[image]

But plotting without `col`:

```
plot(df['rmse_cut'], main = 'RMSE', graticule = TRUE, axes = TRUE, 
bgc = 'gray92', 
pch = 21, lwd = 2, cex = 3,
bg = c('blue', 'green', 'yellow'))
```

[image]

The borders are sorted by the variable `rmse_cut` but the background color is fixed.
How can I use a single color for point borders while using background colors to show the different values from the `rmse_cut` variable?.

Comment: There's probably a more direct route, but you can overplot the points, first plotting the fill, then the strokes (or with different plotting characters). Or just use ggplot, which has solid sf support.

Comment: I'll go with the `ggplot2` option but I realize I have many scripts in `base` R. Perhaps finding a solution to this would save me some time (I think it'll take quite a lot of time to recreate my old plots with `ggplot2`). Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember base plotting! You need to sort out your palettes so that they are consistent, and then call the palette referenced by the value:

```
plotpal <- sf.colors(nlevels(df[['rmse_cut']]),categorical=TRUE)
plot(df['rmse_cut'], main = 'RMSE', graticule = TRUE, axes = TRUE, bgc = 'gray92',
     type="n", pal=plotpal, key.pos=1, reset=FALSE)
plot(df[['geometry']], pch = 21, lwd = 2, cex = 3, bg=plotpal[df[['rmse_cut']]], add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I have to remember base plotting... 
Anyway, inside the first `plot` call the argument `reset = FALSE` is missing (I'm using `sf` 0.6-3), without it nothing happens for me. Thank you.

Comment: @noriega - I'm behind the times a bit clearly with my `sf` version - updated!

Answer (score 2):

Forget base plotting, `geom_sf()` is in the latest CRAN release for `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = rmse_cut)) +
  geom_sf(size = 5, color = "black", shape = 21, stroke = 2) +
  coord_sf(ylim = c(-11,-13))
```

[image]

Since your `lat` values are so tight I expanded the scale a bit manually.

Comment: This seems very interesting, but I think oversimplified my example. Is it possible to add `shapefile` layers to the final plot? and how could I use a palette (like `brewer.pal(3, 'YlOrRd')`) for the background colors? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nevermind I found some info on the web and my results are very impressive but I'm gonna stick with base plot, at least for now.

Comment: sure I understand sticking with base R, but I personally don't know it well enough to help. I can help with the color scaling in `ggplot2` if you decide to come back to the land of layers holler

Comment: That's very nice of you @Nate. I'll keep that in mind when I finally decide to turn to the dark side.